# sprintf corrupting arrays in IAR microcontroller

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, printf

I am currently learning embedded programming, and thus working on an IAR-platform using a TI microcontroller with ARM architecture. Since I am not at all familiar with the technicalities related to this kind of programming, or C programming in general, I would like to ask a basic question:

I have the following simple code snippet:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++)
{
    sinTable[i] = sinf(2*i*dT*PI);
}


for(i = 0; i < NUM_SAMPLES; i++)
{
    char out[32];
    sprintf(out,"sin: %.7f, %.7f;", i*dT, sinTable[i]);
    putString(out);
    delay(DELAY_100US);
}
```

Where  `sinTable[]`  is a global variable of size `NUM_SAMPLES`, `putString(*char)` is a function which writes to an RS232-port, and `delay(float)` is a simple delay-function.

My problem is that once the `sprintf(...)` is called, it corrupts `sinTable`, giving some very peculiar results when plotting the table on the receiver end of the COM-signal.

I don't expect that I run out of memory, as the MC has 64KB SRAM.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: How high is `NUM_SAMPLES` and what is the value of `dT`?

Comment: How do you come to know `sinTable` is corrupted?? The prototype of `sprintf` is `int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );` i.e. values of second and later arguments are `const`, hence cannot be modified by `sprintf`.

Comment: NUM_SAMPLES = 32 and dT = 0.03125f.

I found that sinTable[] was corrupt while using the debugger. Once sprintf is called, some table values change.

Comment: `sprintf` won't corrupt sinTable, unless it was already corrupted.

Comment: Two things I'd look into: 1) IAR's runtimes have options about the level of support for the `printf()` family of functions. I think that usually floating point support is not enabled by default - make sure you have it enabled; 2) the `printf()` family of functions use quite a bit of stack space.  Make sure the stack allocated to your task is adequately large.

Comment: Can you post few values of `sinTable` before and after corruption...

Comment: @Tom More code will be useful to locate the problem.

Comment: Before sprintf(...): http://postimg.org/image/xilkm528r/
after: http://postimg.org/image/javvxhpjv/

Comment: The stack has been allocated 16KB, so I would not expect an overflow.

Comment: @Tom: maybe you can get an idea by setting a data write breakpoint on `sinTable[1]` just before the `snprintf()` loop and see what's going on  when that location gets overwritten.

Comment: The screenshots previously posted are from breakpoints set at the line of sprintf(...), i.e. before sinTable[0] gets converted, and similarly for sinTable[1].

Comment: @Tom So it is the same breakpoint, only different iterations? It may be that it is the `putString(out);` that does the corruption.

Comment: @Tom: try to change `char out[32]` to `char out[200]`. Also also try to change `char out[32]` to `static char out[32]`, and tell us if this changes anything. This not really a solution, but the outcome might give us some clues.

Comment: changing the length of out[] and making it static yields the same result. The values change, but sinTable[] is still corrupt.

The breakpoints are indeed at the same location in different iterations. Red signifies change in the screenshots.

The debugger would suggest that the change happens in sprintf(...), and when doing the computation in sprintf(...) instead of storing them in sinTable, the output is correct.

Comment: @Tom try changing your second loop to `for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)` and then compare the 2 halves.if the 1st half is only corrupted then it may be some implementation problem. but this won't work if the entire array is somehow corrupted on the function call, but worth a try

Comment: As a sidenote: You should always prefer `snprintf` over `sprintf`, because it has proper overflow checking.

Comment: @Tom Could you clarify what you mean by *"when doing the computation in sprintf(...) instead of storing them in sinTable, the output is correct."*? And I still think that you should comment out `putString` call to test if the corruption still happens.

Comment: To clarify my comment above: replacing `sprintf(out, "sin: %.7f, %.7f;", i*dT, sinTable[i])` with `sprintf(out, "sin: %.7f, %.7f;", i*dT, sinf(2*i*dT*PI))` gives the desired output, yet this is not what I require, as my intention is to do some computation and then plot them on the recieving end of the RS232.

Removing `putString(out)` yields no change, neither does using `snprintf(...)`, although I agree using this would be better.

Comment: On a related note: Converting to HEX and then applying `sprint(...)` also corrupts `sinTable[]`.

Comment: Unless there is interrupt routine overwriting random memory locations on the background, it smells like an overflow of some kind. You are not getting any compiler warnings? You could try to enable remarks (both compiler and linker) to see if compiler see anything suspicous. Also enable linker map creation and see if there is anything near `sinTable` that could overflow there.

Comment: @Tom: Break on the `sprintf()` line. Then in the debugger's "Breakpoints" window, right click and select "New Breakpoint/Data...". In the "Break At:" field put `sinTable[1]` and select the "Write" radio button and press OK.  Now step over the `sprintf()`. The debugger should break exactly where the array is being overwritten.  A backtrace and/or other analysis should tell you why.

Comment: Are you using sprintf anywhere else?  It's possible that the system's sprintf implementation isn't reentrant and two calls the sprintf are crossing badly.  Or, I've also worked on systems that have a bad float format conversion, try %d or %u (multiply to shift the decimal point if you need).

Comment: In addition to the things mentioned in the other answers and comments, your communication setup seems fishy. What does `putString` do, does it copy characters into a UART FIFO buffer and then exit, or does it wait for every single character to get sent? In case you merely copy everything into a FIFO buffer, your code will print garbage, because a 100us delay is not enough to get everything sent out.

Comment: Please post the code of `putString`.

Comment: @Lundin, `putString()` writes a character to the buffer, waits for it to be sent and then repeats until the end of the string. It is very simple, but is unfortunately not the issue.

@Digikata, converting the float to an int still corrupts the table when using `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your stack pointer is on a 64-bit boundary when `main` is reached.

The symptom your are seeing is typical of a stack aligned on an odd 32-bit boundary. Everything seems to work properly until a double is used as a variadac argument. This breaks when the code expects such arguments to be on 8-byte boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further review:
I suspect that Michael Burr's response regarding stack utilization was on the right track. Selecting a smaller printf library might be sufficient, but if you can increase your stack size, that seems safer. Note that the IAR C/C++ Development Guide includes info on linker stack usage analysis.

Original:
When I upgraded from IAR 6.1 (licensed) to 6.4 (kickstart), I ran into a similar problem - vsnprintf was writing "all over RAM", even though the return value indicated the number of characters written was well within the target bounds. The "solution" was to avoid the printf library that has multibyte support.

Project Options > General > Library Options > printf small w/o multi-byte

might want to also uncheck

Project Options > C/C++ Compiler / Language 2 / enable multibyte

I tried to report this to IAR, but since my support contract is expired ...

Unfortunately, a similar problem is back with IAR 7.3.4, and the multibyte "fix" does NOT seem to be sufficient. Happens with both sprintf() and snprintf(), although the out-of-bounds corruption is not identical between those 2.

Answer (score 0):

You seem pretty confident that your result string is only 31 characters long. The only way to corrupt another variable with your sprintf statement is that your result string is longer than 32 bytes (31 chars and a nul-byte), therefore overwriting other parts of memory. Make your numbers smaller or make your temporary buffer larger.

Comment: Using the debugger I find that the memory regions do not overlap. Assuming that it still does and that it is not showing in the debugger, when choosing a word-length of 256 the result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to anyone who have suggested a solution to this problem. I eventually ended up writing a conversion method that gives a hex-representation of the string and transmitted that instead, omitting the  `sprintf(...)` completely.

It is very crude, but suits my needs.