# snprintf() printout out of bounds

Tags: c, embedded, printf, iar

C newbie here. Been messing around with an embedded microcontroller, I've noticed that when I set up a buffer:`char buffer[100]` and then print to it: `snprintf(buffer, 20, "Just A test");`, my memory map shows that not just the bytes I expected are changed.

As a result, unintended variables seem to get affected. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: okay I took a screenshot of the situation. The memory map in black has just been init'd to all FF's. However after the sprintf prints to the buffer, it produces the expected changes as well as the not expected (not expected highlighted in the red box and also in red underneath that box. I'm more concerned about the red box because it's seemingly overwriting some of my intended changes)

[image]

EDIT2: it appears that increasing the stack size helps with this. I think I have a version of this problem: [sprintf corrupting arrays in IAR microcontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295028/sprintf-corrupting-arrays-in-iar-microcontroller)

Comment: Devil is in the details. Show us the code.  (indent 4 spaces and it will format nicely here)

Comment: Which bytes are also changing?  Ones beyond the first 12 bytes within the 20 you told `snprintf()` it could use, or completely unrelated ones?  Had you called `snprintf()` — or any other function in that family before?  If not, then it could be that `snprintf()` is loading some locale or other information that it needs to work correctly.

Comment: try `snprintf (buffer, 20, "%s", "Just A test");`

Comment: try using strlen("Just A test") + 1 as length argument in snprintf. something like snprintf (buffer, strlen("Just A test")+1, "Just A test").

Comment: @user3457614 If you think its stack corruption, you can try using heap for buffer. And if that works fine, then we are sure it may be stack corruption

Comment: @user3457614 If you are worried about 89-96 bytes, its becasue you have not initialized your `char[100]` array. If you initialized it to NULL, you'll not see those values in there.

Comment: @Pawan ITYM zero-initialized. null pointers are not suitable for initializing `char`.

Comment: @Pawan shouldnt the memset operation be enough? Either way, after memset the whole block is FF's after sprintf the first few bytes are changed as expected, BUT also the bytes at the end are  changed. This should not happen.

Comment: I'm thinking about the buffer address: `0x20000000`. Could you post your icf  linker script, please?

Comment: If supported by the debugger set a write access breakpoint of address 0x20000058, and it will stop at precisely the instruction that is writing there - at that point you can check the stack pointer.  Is `data` on the stack? How big was the stack, and how big did you make it to "solve" the problem?  Does your linker support stack usage analysis? (according to [this](https://www.iar.com/kr/support/resources/articles/mastering-stack-and-heap-for-system-reliability/) it does).  Verify that you have an appropriate stack size - snprintf() itself may be quite hungry.

Comment: Furthermore if stdout is buffered and interrupt driven, the interrupt stack may be too small and overrunning into the main thread stack.